# Rewriting URL's does not work

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, web-config

I was just trying to rewrite the following url:

> http://*******.nl/news

(/news is also a rewrote page, it comes from views/news.html and the index gets the page by a php request from index.php?p=news but don't worry about that)

to:

> http://*******.nl/plug/cproxy?key=news

But it doesn't seem to be working... And no, I do not want to rewrite the second url to the first, it is just like how I want it.

Can someone help me out with this?

The way I did it was like this (I am working with web.config instead of .htaccess) :

```
<rule name="rule 16T">
    <match url="^plug/cproxy?key=news$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?p=news"  />
</rule>
```

I would really appreciate your help guys!!

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards!

---

Edit: it is not a mixup, because when I change the 
    `<match url="^plug/cproxy?key=news$"  />`
to `<match url="^plug/cproxy/key/news$"  />` and then I visit this plug/cproxy/key/news url, the page in the action URL just shows up like it is supposed to, so I guess it is just something about the question mark (?) and equal to mark (=) in the match URL...

Also escaping the question mark didn't do anything (I escaped it like \? )

Comment: Escape the `?` because that has a special meaning in regex and you want it to be literal. I'm also not sure if it should be `match url`, is there a `query string` parameter/element?

Comment: @chris85 I think the match url is right, because I already rewrote some other pages/url's and they are working fine so...

++ Do I just need to escape the question mark like \? or is there another way?

Comment: Okay, yea I wasn't sure about if the query string would be there. Yes, that should escape the question mark, `\?`. Also not sure if that is a mix up in the question or the XML but the example URLs dont match the rewrite rule.

Comment: Also the `^` means it will only match if the URL is `plug/cproxy?key=news` - to the previous remark about URI vs. query string, But if you say other ones worked...  I'd assume the subject was more like `domain..nl/plug/cproxy?key=news`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple mixup, try this

```
<rule name="">
    <match url="^news" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="plug/cproxy?key=news" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a mixup, because when I change the question mark and equal to sign in the match url to a forwardslash, it works fine, so the ^plug/cproxy?key=news$ becomes: ^plug/cproxy/key/news$ but that is not what I want...

Comment: Check the edit in my post, added some more information, hopefully you can help me out!